# The discrepancy between the two values in units of sigmas?

Tags: statistics

Assuming gaussian error distributions, how to calculate the discrepancy between the two values in units of sigmas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how big one sigma is, for your gaussian distribution.
It could be narrow, or it could be wide.
You get that by calculating the variance, and taking its square root.

Then just divide the difference between the two values by sigma.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).